# How can I run do-release-upgrade if apt won't update all my packages?

Tags: apt, repository, do-release-upgrade, 22.10, mozilla

The situation is that as I use a Mozilla repo, and that repo doesn't have updates limited by Ubuntu install (or it did them wrongly) so `sudo apt full-upgrade` tells me 3 new packages are waiting to be installed, but digging into the dependencies showsthat it wants a newer version of `libc6` and `libx11-xcb1` in order to be able to update me to the latest Firefox 108.0 and Thunderbird 102.6.

Now looking at [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com) I see the required versions of the libraries are in the Kinetic (22.10) repos. But I'm on 22.04 (Jammy) and can't upgrade the Mozilla packages until the release upgrade has been done; but can't do the release upgrade until all the packages are installed ... that's a problem!

What I've tried:

I looked for a way to force `do-release-upgrade` as clearly the Mozilla packages will be able to install once I've updated to Kinetic, the libraries needed are in that version of Kubuntu. No dice, there's no way to force the update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me (answering my own question): I went into /etc/apt/sources.list and copied the first line:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ jammy main restricted
```

and rewrote it for Kinetic, I added the following line, I did not remove the Jammy line:

```
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ kinetic main restricted
```

Then I ran `sudo apt update`, it took a longer time than normal and reported thousands of updates. I **only** ran the updates that Firefox and Thunderbird had wanted, manually, via `sudo aptitude` (I think you could use `apt` or `synaptic` or any other package manager as long as you have tight control of it) and made sure that only a minimal number of packages/dependencies were being automatically added. The updates are both minor updates and so *should* be compatible with everything on Jammy; this is a little risky I think, but for minor updates and small numbers of packages it seems relatively low risk.

Once the demanded libc6 (2.36-0ubuntu4) and libx11-xcb1 (1.8.1-2) packages and their dependencies had been installed, I quit out of aptitude.

I then reverted the change to  `sources.list` by commenting out the Kinetic line; cleared apt using `sudo apt autoremove; sudo apt  autoclean`; then ran apt for an update and full upgrade with `sudo apt update; sudo apt full-upgrade`.

Finally, the 3 Mozilla packages -- Firefox 108.0, Thunderbird 102.6 and a Thunderbird locale file -- installed.

Now that apt was fully up-to-date, I could run `do-release-upgrade` with:

```
do-release-upgrade -m desktop --allow-third-party
```

The install has now completed, and the system is working as expected.

Note: in the past, I've updated by changing the all the `/etc/apt/sources.list` entries and the `source.list.d/` file entries from one release name to another and just running an apt-update followed by dist-upgrade (for which full-upgrade is a synonym). That might have worked here; what I did just seemed like a quick fix without me having to look at whether do-release-upgrade was doing anything fancy under the hood. HTH. YMMV.